# Cordova doesn't add data to URL (AJAX)

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, url

I'm sending an Jquery.Ajax request to a server which is hosting a .asmx web service.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://IP-destination/myFolder/WebService.asmx/LogonUser',
        cache: 'true',
       data: {          
            'username':get_cookie('username'),
            'password':get_cookie('password'),
            'environment':get_cookie('environment')
        },   
        dataType: 'jsonp',

        beforeSend: function(){$.mobile.loading('show', 'a', 'Laddar...', false); alert("go");},

        error: function(a, b, c){
            $.mobile.loading('hide','a');
              alert(a + b+ c);

        },

        success: function(response){
             $.mobile.loading('hide','a');
            alert("success");
             self.loginUser_cb(response);
        }
    });
```

While sending data through my browser, emulator or "Legacy Hybrid build (Intel XDK) for android" everything works great.

But when I use Cordova (still android, works on IOS) the request get an "500 Internal Server Error".

It seems like my URL is missing my data parameters:
http://oi60.tinypic.com/21jvb5y.jpg

When I use my browser the URL is correct with the data parameter in the end of the url: /LogonUser?callback=jQuery19105695250731240461_1425028837473&username=MyUserName&password=Secret&environment=Dev

My question is: What could possibly cause this in Cordova Android but work great
in the emulator/ios/Hybrid Legacy build? The URL seem to be cut short.

Comment: What happens if you change jsonp to json? You don't need to use jsonp under Cordova.

Comment: Same output 500 Internal Server Error, URL is still missing the data parameter. Thanks

Comment: Fun fact, my response header content-type is set to "text/plain" while using Cordova on the device, but is set to "application/json" on the emulator which is working. How can that be?

Comment: Dumb question - do those cookie values exist? If you change them to static values, does it work?

Comment: That isn't a dumb question at all, but yes they do exist and I have tried static values :/ I wonder if there is something wrong with the webconfig in the .asmx. If codova demands some different settings, but yet again, the emulator wouldn't work.. hmmm

Comment: If you debug using remote debugging in Chrome, and you examine the network requests (which I think you did), do you see something weird with the request info?

Comment: Raymond, I went back and instead of using variables with the cookie values or the cookie itself - I entered static values. That solves the problem! Thank you <3  For future reference, how do I mark your answer as correct? Can't find where lol

Comment: well, I'm not sure I solved it per se - I was just trying to simplify as much as possible. If you want, I can add what I said as an answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look to simplify things as much as possible and see if the get_cookie portion is failing for you. Try removing that and using static values. If it works, it means your cookies may not exist as you think they should and you should write logic to handle that.